# how to get the name of a location with gelocation python

Tags: python, geolocation

i have coordinate of a place and i know how to convert it to the address :

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
print(location.address)
```

this code gives me the address of the coordinate but i need to also get the name of the place like if it is the coordinate of a cafe or hotel i need to get it's name as well.
i can't figure out how i can do it!

Comment: Check `location.raw`.

Comment: Tnx it works! and is there any way also the get the type of the place directly?like cafe or hotel or attractions?

Comment: No, you can only get address, altitude, lat, lon or point [directly](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=location#geopy.location.Location).